# Disk Utility "restore from" list does not include any volumes

Tags: mac, high-sierra, disk-utility, restore

I want to copy a volume from an old MacBook Pro to a new one.  I mounted the old one using Target Firewire Mode.  I made a new APFS volume on the new machine.  When I tell Disk Utility that I want to restore to the new volume, the list of volumes to restore from has nothing on it.  Why?  Is it because the old volumes are HFS+ format, rather than APFS?  Will I be able to make a disk image, and then restore from that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the route of making a disk image and restoring from that.  I got an error message saying that an APFS volume can only be restored from an APFS volume.  So apparently I must find another way to copy all the data.